# why is my query isnt excecuting while i set the parameters

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, parameter-passing

I have a java file which interacts with the backend db and retrieves rows for me,

the code part where my java interacts with the db is as follows,

```
 try {
        con = DBconnection.getConnection();
        System.out.println("in get_camplist");
        String brand = request.getParameter("brand_id");
        System.out.println(brand);
        int bid = Integer.parseInt(brand);
        System.out.println(bid);
        String start_date = request.getParameter("s_date");
        String end_date = request.getParameter("e_date");
        System.out.println(start_date);

        prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(dbquery.getContentTable);
        prepStmt.setInt(1, bid);
        prepStmt.setString(2, start_date);
        prepStmt.setString(3, end_date);
        rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();

        tblist = new ArrayList<Cont_foc_tab>();
        Cont_foc_tab tb = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            tb = new Cont_foc_tab(rs.getString("video_Name"), rs.getLong("views"), rs.getLong("likes"), rs.getLong("comments"), rs.getLong("shares"), rs.getLong("engagement"));
            tblist.add(tb);
        }
```

**dbquery.getContentTable query is as folows**

```
 public static String getContentTable = "select  a.vidid as     video_id,b.Vid_Name as video_Name,b.Vid_URL as url,  " +
"             a.Views as views,a.likes as likes,a.comments as     comments,a.shares as shares,a.Engagement as engagement  " +
 "             from ((select VidID as vidid,SUM(Yt_Views) as     Views,SUM(Yt_Likes) as likes,  " +
 "             SUM(Yt_Comments) as comments,SUM(Yt_Shares) as     shares,round(((cast((SUM(Yt_Likes) + SUM(Yt_Shares) + SUM(Yt_Comments)) as     float)/SUM(Yt_Views))*100),2) as Engagement  " +
"             from  SocMet_VidMetrics_Fact  " +
"             where VidID in (select distinct VidID from     SocMet_VidMetrics_Fact where ProdID= ? ) and   " +
"             (DateKey>=(select DateKey from DimDate where Date= ? )  " +
"             and DateKey<=(select DateKey from DimDate where Date= ?     ))  " +
"             group by VidID) a left join SocMet_VidDetails_Dim b on     a.VidID=b.VidID) " +
"             where a.vidid in     ('-wK47AqI7P0','_8PdkNMNrBo','cjHJCF0seMQ','7aCUq-cPGbQ','5hSUbGStxhY','HPXHV6iHzIk','BLbxRvjDzd0','kvD0h-Ce52c','CcWnfduAS_E','PeHbEGKyBiY','A5HKiUe4KaU','bGcoQN-crzg','BMGMi2Webd0','YSVL4FvFhvw','vZgIbWTEoMA','OFCnDURIPQg'); ";
```

when i try to execute the same query by passing the same values in the sql server management studio it works fine and returns rows when i try to pass the parameters dynamically it doesn't return any row,

**sql query in the sql management studio**

```
select  a.vidid as video_id,b.Vid_Name as video_Name,b.Vid_URL as url, 
         a.Views as views,a.likes as likes,a.comments as comments,a.shares as shares,a.Engagement as engagement 
         from ((select VidID as vidid,SUM(Yt_Views) as Views,SUM(Yt_Likes) as likes, 
         SUM(Yt_Comments) as comments,SUM(Yt_Shares) as shares,round(((cast((SUM(Yt_Likes) + SUM(Yt_Shares) + SUM(Yt_Comments)) as float)/SUM(Yt_Views))*100),2) as Engagement 
         from  SocMet_VidMetrics_Fact 
         where VidID in (select distinct VidID from SocMet_VidMetrics_Fact where ProdID= 20 ) and  
         (DateKey>=(select DateKey from DimDate where Date='01/01/2012' ) 
         and DateKey<=(select DateKey from DimDate where Date='07/31/2014' )) 
         group by VidID) a left join SocMet_VidDetails_Dim b on a.VidID=b.VidID)
         where a.vidid in ('-wK47AqI7P0','_8PdkNMNrBo','cjHJCF0seMQ','7aCUq-cPGbQ','5hSUbGStxhY','HPXHV6iHzIk','BLbxRvjDzd0','kvD0h-Ce52c','CcWnfduAS_E','PeHbEGKyBiY','A5HKiUe4KaU','bGcoQN-crzg','BMGMi2Webd0','YSVL4FvFhvw','vZgIbWTEoMA','OFCnDURIPQg');
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the named parameters instead (e.g. `WHERE Date = @givenDate`)?? Maybe your problem is just the provided parameters are not in the correct sequence

Comment: Why are you using `setString` for a date?

Comment: i m sure that the parameters are in the correct sequence i ll try to do the @givenDate though

Comment: I m getting my Date as string from the front end @Ic

Comment: @Desolator can u give me an example for the named parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like this `TO_DATE('<your_date_string>', 'yyyy/mm/dd')`. you have the datatype as date and you are comparing as string.

Also I would suggest you to use log4jdbc connectionspy library which will help  you in debugging what query you code actually fired .
you can wrap the connection object like this

```
con = new net.sf.log4jdbc.ConnectionSpy(con);
```

Comment: i tried doing something like Date s_date;
            s_date = (Date) formatter1.parse(start_date);
           
            java.sql.Date sqlS_Date;
            sqlS_Date = new java.sql.Date(s_date.getTime());
            

            prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(dbquery.getContentTable);
            prepStmt.setInt(1, bid);
            prepStmt.setDate(2, sqlS_Date);

Comment: Still its returning an empty list

Comment: @shijohari i also get an exception called "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 3 is out of range."